# How can I remove a shadow in iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, shadow

I am using the standard way of making shadows from a button programmatically, but I would like to shadow to no longer exist after I am done with the button.  I could set opacity to 0, but would the shadow still exist and if so would it still tax the system.  thanks

this gives an error

```
tempButton.superview.layer.shadowOffset = nil;
    tempButton.superview.layer.shadowRadius = nil;
    tempButton.superview.layer.shadowOpacity = nil;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS add / remove shadow from a view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751163/ios-add-remove-shadow-from-a-view)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I usually do the following to be safe.

```
  [[tempButton layer] setShadowOpacity:0.0];
  [[tempButton layer] setShadowRadius:0.0];
  [[tempButton layer] setShadowColor:nil];
```

Quartz is highly optimized and will not waste any time rendering if it doesn't have to.

Comment: +1 but I wonder if `[[tempButton layer] setShadowColor:nil];` is really safe. The documentation says the default is opaque black but doesn't specify how nil is handled (and relying on undocumented behaviour is never safe). Personally I'm going to skip that one.

Comment: `nil` seems to work fine, but if you want to play it safe go with [UIColor clearColor].CGColor. That works fine as well and is safe.

Answer (score 1):

I would just remove the button, and replace it with an identical (but non-shadowed) button.  Or keep both around and hide/unhide one of them.  Sometimes it's easier to create a new UI object than munge around with an existing one.